# Rectangle as a delegate in ListView make highlightItem to not work

Tags: qml

In the Below code if the delegate Item is a Rectangle the highlight does not work even
though Rectangle inherits Item, is this a bug, or am i missing something.

```
ListView {
    width: 200
    height: 500
    focus: true
    highlight: Component {
        Rectangle {
            width: 200
            height: 20
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    model: ListModel {ListElement {name: "dummy 1"} ListElement {name: "dummy 2"}}
    delegate: Item { // If Item is replaced with Rectangle highlight does not work even though Rectangle inherits Item
        width: 200
        height: 20
        Text {
            text: name
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the color of the delegate rectangle to be transparent. By default the color of rectangle is white and Item is transparent.

```
ListView {
    width: 200
    height: 500
    focus: true
    highlight: Component {
        Rectangle {
           width: 200
           height: 20
           color: "red"
        }
    }

    model: ListModel {ListElement {name: "dummy 1"} ListElement {name: "dummy 2"}}
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 200
        height: 20
        color: "transparent"
        Text {
            text: name
        }
    }
}
```